# select a change to the url

Tags: url, select

select a change to the url

```
<form name="language" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <select onchange = "document.language.submit()" name="lang">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $lang['select-language']; ?></option>
            <option value="en"><?php echo $lang['en']; ?></option>
            <option value="es"><?php echo $lang['es']; ?></option>
            <option value="fr"><?php echo $lang['fr']; ?></option>
         </select>
    </form>
```

Help remake in URL

```
<a href="">en</a>
<a href="">es</a>
<a href="">fr</a>
```

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: you need to choose the language was not select a url